# Why can't I connect to the internet at all with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, internet, connection

So one day I was using my server and decided since I had a page of updates that had been piling up. That was my first problem... I had heard never to update things on Ubuntu but I disregarded that. Anyways I updated to 12.04 and when it was done it would not let me connect to the internet. I have tried re-installing the operating system but to no avail. I have been using Ubuntu for a few months but I'm not to good with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Ubuntu installed the drivers for your hardware? Are you connecting through ethernet or wifi? A little more information is needed here.

Open terminal and type: `sudo lshw -c network` and look for your network interface. Check and see if it's broadcasting or not.

If you need more help with it, run the command and post your results here.